# Why program executes correctly for subprocess.Popen calling one .exe but not the other?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

so I am trying to run a simple subprocess.Popen to run the GUI for a program and then make a bunch of automated clicks with pyautogui. I'm encountering a problem where when I put one path to a GUI, it opens the GUI and the clicks work just fine. However, when I substitute it out for a path to a different GUI, the clicks don't happen, BUT, it prints out "Finished Clicks", showing that the program did fully execute. I am confused however, why these clicks aren't happening. Here is my code.

```py
def gui_call_thread():
    subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\arduino.exe"], shell = True)
    # works for C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\arduino.exe
    # does not work for C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Texas Instruments\\TX7316 EVM\\TX7316 EVM.exe
    time.sleep(10) # wait for GUI to load before executing clicks
    pyautogui.click(1076,537)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(1065,558)
    time.sleep(0.5) 
    pyautogui.click(1060,643)
    print('Executing...')
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.click(224,110)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(249,135)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(922,507)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(1139,459, clicks = 2)
    print('Finished Clicks')  

gui_call_thread()
```

Comment: If nobody but you has the two files, how are we supposed to say?

Comment: BTW, I would generally suggest avoiding `shell=True` unless you have a specific and compelling reason to use it. Starting a shell can hide real errors, because the problem gets reported to the shell, not to the caller.

Comment: You can't click in the same positions for two different programs and assume that it does something. Do these coordinates make any sense? How do you recognize a successful click?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it does not do the same thing, but the point is that the clicks actually happen when calling one program and do not happen at all for the other. The clicks might not do anything but at least they are visible and happening in one case right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried to avoid that but I get a OS permissions error when I have it set to False so I think I need to use it.

Comment: How do you know the shell isn't getting the same permissions error? :)

Comment: ...which is to say, `shell=True` can be _hiding_ the error (so things still fail, but without reporting that failure) instead of _solving_ it. Given that context, I strongly recommend treating it as a permissions problem instead of a code problem.

Comment: Again, how do you find out that clicks are happening or not? They might be happening but you can't observe anything

Comment: The mouse stays in the same place, before I could see it moving around and clicking on stuff. Is there some way that it could get hidden that I'm not aware of? How would I check if this is the case? Also how do I check the terminal for the permissions error? Sorry for so many questions!

Comment: One thing you might do is poll whether the executable is actually running in the failing case. You can call `poll()` on the object -- if that returns `None` it's still running; anything else is a return code indicating success or failure.

Comment: As for capturing output... it depends. Setting `stderr=PIPE` will let you capture error messages, but if nothing is reading from that pipeline in real time you can get into race conditions that way; it's a topic for a separate question more than a comment (but thankfully, there _have already_ been plenty of questions asked-and-answered on the subject).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Tried your advice with the poll() to check if the executable was still running and it was indeed still running. Also I added 2 print(pyautogui.position()) statements to track the current mouse position during execution) and it does not move at all. Any further advice? Also how do I check the shell to see if it is also getting the same permissions error? When I run the code in the VS Code terminal with shell = False I get the error in that terminal but when I set it equal to True the code just executes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved this, simply, the code was clicking, but the gui I was trying to automate had 2 layers, a pop up type layer, and an under-gui. Simply, the clicks were happening, but not on the layer of screen that I wanted.

Comment: please edit your post (possibly with code) to let everyone know

Comment: If the way the question was solved isn't likely to help other people with similar problems, it's best to just delete the question.